# Trying to detect if 2 specific bodies are colliding with matter.js in phaser 3

Tags: phaser-framework, matter.js

I'm trying to add enemies to my platformer game using the matter physics engine however using the this.matter.world.on collisionactive function only checks collision between the floor and enemy after the player jumps once. I'm currently using labels to check for collision. I have tried adding extra conditions but have only been able to allow the player to infinitely jump. i.e- it is checking the labels of what is colliding.

Collision checking code:

```
    this.matter.world.on("collisionactive", (e,o1,o2) => {
        if(o1.label == 'floor' && o2.label == 'player')
        {
            this.touchingGround = true;
            console.log('touching')
        }
    });
```

Enemy creation function:
Right now the enemies are cubes that are created at the cursor when the player presses f

```
function createEnemy(scene,x,y)
{
    enemy = scene.matter.add.image(x,y,'enemy').setScale(1.5)
    enemy.body.label = 'enemy'
}
```

Comment: Can you show, the enemy code, that doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't completely understand the problem, but if you have an issue with *checking/finding* all current collisions, you can use the `pairs` property of the **event-object-argument** ([link to the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Physics.Matter.Events.html#event:COLLISION_ACTIVE__anchor)), which is passed to the ***physics-callback*** function. This property should contain, the other collisions.

> *"...The `event.pairs` array may contain more colliding bodies. ..."*

**Here a short demo:**

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';
var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 11 * 16, 
    height: 6 * 16,
    zoom: 2,
    pixelArt: true,
    scene: {
        preload: preload,
        create: create
    },
    physics: {
        default: 'matter',
        matter: {
            gravity: {
                y:.3
            },
            debug:true
        }
    },
    banner: false
};

function preload (){
    this.load.image('mario-tiles', 'https://labs.phaser.io/assets/tilemaps/tiles/super-mario.png');
}

function create (){
    var level = [
      '0'.repeat(11).split(''),
      '0'.repeat(11).split(''),
      '0'.repeat(11).split(''),
      '0'.repeat(11).split(''),
      '0'.repeat(11).split(''),
      '0'.repeat(11).split('').map( _ => 14),
    ];        
   
    var map = this.make.tilemap({ data: level, tileWidth: 16, tileHeight: 16 });
    var tiles = map.addTilesetImage('mario-tiles');
    var layer = map.createLayer(0, tiles, 0, 0);

    this.add.text(4, 4, 'click to jump', {color:'#9EE6FF', fontSize:10})
        .setOrigin(0);
    var info = this.add.text(4, 14, 'waiting ...', {color:'#ffffff', fontSize:10})
        .setOrigin(0);

    let enemy1 = this.add.rectangle(60.25, 5, 8, 8, 0xfff000)
        .setOrigin(0.5);
    let player = this.add.rectangle(60, 20, 8, 8, 0xffffff);
    
    layer.setCollision([14]);
    
    this.matter.add.gameObject(enemy1);
   
    this.matter.add.gameObject(player);
    this.matter.world.convertTilemapLayer(layer, {label:'floor'});
    
    player.body.label = 'player';
    enemy1.body.label = 'enemy';
    
    this.input.on('pointerup', _=> player.setVelocityY(-3))
    
    player.setVelocityY(-1)

    this.matter.world.on("collisionactive", (e, o1, o2) => {

        let text = 'p: ';
        
        if( e.pairs.some (pair => pair.bodyA.label == 'player' && pair.bodyB.label =='floor' )) {
            text += 'touch floor ';
        }
        
        if( e.pairs.some (pair => pair.bodyA.label == 'enemy' && pair.bodyB.label =='player' )) {
            text += 'touch enemy ';
        }
        
        if( e.pairs.some (pair => pair.bodyA.label == 'enemy' && pair.bodyB.label =='floor' )) {
            text += '\ne: touch floor';
        }
        info.setText(text);            
    });
}

new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```

Comment: How do you know the order of `bodyA` and `bodyB`? E.g. you check for bodyA==player and bodyB==floor but you don't check for the reverse. Are `bodyA` and `bodyB` always in the order they were added to Matter?

Comment: @BrianMorearty yes, you are right, it is due to the order they were added. I could find the documentation, but when I find it I will post it.